# Scheduled with fixed delay in quartz scheduler?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I have developed a job which I want to run say after every 5 mins, but there may be certain circumstances where the job completion time may exceeds 5 mins.

I am using quartz scheduler to schedule my job using a cron expression. Is there any way to tell quartz scheduler to hold the next run of job untill first one is completed?

I am looking for something similar to -

```
private static final ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
executor.scheduledWithFixedDelay(..);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [StatefulJob](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/api/1.8.1/org/quartz/StatefulJob.html). From the docs:

> stateful jobs are not allowed to
>   execute concurrently, which means new
>   triggers that occur before the
>   completion of the execute(xx) method
>   will be delayed.

Answer (score -1):

http://yongjun-jiao.blogspot.com/2010/08/quartz-crontrigger-scdeuling-policy.html.
If you use spring scheduling concepts http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/dynamic-language.html