# Apache Camel With Quartz - No Concurrent Execution

Tags: java, apache-camel, quartz-scheduler, apache-servicemix

I want to use camel->quartz component to schedule some job to be done at specified time interval.

But I want that in synchronized manner. Means, Next execution of scheduled job should only start after completion of current execution.

I created Route and Scheduler Service for Servicemix.

**QuartzRoute.java**

```
public class QuartzRoute extends RouteBuilder {
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {

    from("quartz://myGroup/myTimerName?cron=0/1+*+*+*+*+?").process(new SchedulerService());
}
```

}

**SchedulerService.java**

```
public class SchedulerService implements Processor {

public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

    System.out.println("I'm running every 5 sec...");
    Thread.sleep(5000);     
    System.out.println("Exiting iteration ");
}
```

}

Here, I want "I'm running every 5 sec..." and "Exiting iteration " to be printed in same order every time.
In sort i want this SchedulerService to be executed again only after completion of current execution.

Answer (score 5):

Use the stateful=true option of the quartz component. See [Scheduled with fixed delay in quartz scheduler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063482/scheduled-with-fixed-delay-in-quartz-scheduler)

*"stateful jobs are not allowed to execute concurrently, which means new triggers that occur before the completion of the execute(xx) method will be delayed."*

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. Can i define _stateful_ property in case of `from("quartz://myGroup/myTimerName?cron=0/1+*+*+*+*+?").process(new SchedulerService());` ? If yes than how ?

Comment: Just add the option to your uri, eg:

`from("quartz://myGroup/myTimerName?cron=0/1+*+*+*+*+?&stateful=true").process(new SchedulerService());`